# Is there an efficient way to colorize text in a bash prompt without two calls?

Tags: bash, prompt

Efficient way to colorize text in a bash prompt without two calls?

There are plenty of resources around the place about customizing PS1. The critical points here are:

- It's possible to call a custom function to generate text, resulting in custom text
- It's possible for such a function to emit custom color codes
- Non-printing text (like color codes) needs to be marked to make word wrapping work
- It's NOT possible for a custom function to do that marking.

I may be wrong on the last point, and if there's a way, that would perfectly solve this.

Here's a simplified and somewhat contrived example that's topologically similar, if that makes sense, to the one I'm tinkering with. I have an external command (call it `generate_text`) which produces on stdout either "OK" or some one-word message. It may also emit nothing at all. Those three states should be shown in the prompt: if it emits nothing, leave the prompt exactly as it is (`user@hostname:path$`); if it emits OK, put a green "OK " before the prompt; if anything else, put that text in red.

My current solution is to have a custom function that invokes generate_text and either emits its text or emits a color code based on it, and then call that function twice:

```
generate_prompt()
{
    txt=`generate_text`
    [ -z "$txt" ] && exit # The empty case. Produce nothing.
    $1 && echo "##$msg## " || case $msg in
        'OK') echo -e '\e[1;32m'; ;; # Green for OK
        *) echo -e "\e[1;31m"; ;; # Red for anything else
    esac
}
PS1='\[$(generate_prompt false)\]$(generate_prompt true)\[\e[0m\]'$PS1
```

This means I have to call generate_text twice and assume that they'll return the same string (which will normally be the case, but it's theoretically possible that state could change between the two invocations). This strikes me as somewhat wasteful. Is there a convenient way to emit both a non-printing color code and a piece of text from within the same function?

Comment: Are those two calls causing a problem?  Are you getting some sort of slowdown because of them?

Comment: @AndyLester: I think it's only ever a problem when it has to touch the disk (meaning the second invocation will be cached anyway), but it just feels wrong to calculate twice, once for the color and once for the text. The accepted answer below is exactly what I want: do something once, and save two pieces of information.

Comment: I'll suggest that it may be premature optimization to fix problem based on "I think" and "it just feels".  Without measuring, you don't know if you've actually achieved anything, and how much you've improved.

Comment: @AndyLester: Ehh, true. I should know better than to performance-optimize without profiling! But since there's an easy fix, I'm going to just use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use PROMPT_COMMAND to calculate all required values, and then using them in your prompt:

```
generate_prompt() {
  color="" message=""
  txt=$(generate_text)
  [[ -z $txt ]] && return

  message="##$txt##"
  [[ $txt == OK ]] && color=$'\e[1;32m' || color=$'\e[1;31m'
}
PROMPT_COMMAND=generate_prompt
PS1='\[$color\]$message\[\e[0m\]'$PS1
```

Note that PROMPT_COMMAND is sometimes already configured to set the xterm title, in which case you can append to it instead.

Comment: Thanks! That looks like what I need. I'll tinker with this next week and make it work, but on the face of it, I think that's going to be perfect.

Answer (score 3):

This is undocumented so probably not a good solution but appears to work.  It uses internal knowledge of the bash prompting which indicates that text between \001 and \002 characters do not count towards the number of visible characters in the prompt string.

```
generate_prompt()
{
    local txt=$(generate_text)
    case "$txt" in
        '') ;;
        OK) echo -e "\001\e[1;32m\002 $txt \001\e[0m\002"; ;; # Green for OK
         *) echo -e "\001\e[1;31m\002 $txt \001\e[0m\002"; ;; # Red for anything else
    esac
}
PS1='$(generate_prompt)'$PS1
```

The bash source which expands the prompt string contain the following comment which was used to formulate the above solution:

```
/* Current implementation:
    \001 (^A) start non-visible characters
    \002 (^B) end non-visible characters
   all characters except \001 and \002 (following a \001) are copied to
   the returned string; all characters except those between \001 and
   \002 are assumed to be `visible'. */
```

Comment: @chepner Agreed, but somehow I couldn't get the '\[' and '\]' to produce the correct output.  Perhaps I had the escaping of the '\' incorrect.  If you can get this to work, please let know and I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering if the called function could emit \[ \] boundaries! This is a good tip and I'm upvoting it as it's likely to be of value (or at least interest) to someone who comes looking, but depending on implementation details is dangerous.

Comment: In fact this is the only way to drop the `PS1` Variable and use a good nice **readable** bash function.