# Bash PS1: line wrap issue with non-printing characters from an external command

Tags: linux, bash, escaping, command-prompt, prompt

I am using an external command to populate my bash prompt, which is run each time PS1 is evaluated. However, I have a problem when this command outputs non-printable characters (like color escape codes).
Here is an example:

```
$ cat green_cheese.sh 
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "\033[32mcheese\033[0m"

$ export PS1="\$(./green_cheese.sh) \$"
cheese $ # <- cheese is green!
cheese $ <now type really long command>
```

The canonical way of dealing with non-printing characters in the PS1 prompt is to enclose them in `\[` and `\]` escape sequences. The problem is that if you do this from the external command those escapes are not parsed by the PS1 interpreter:

```
$ cat green_cheese.sh 
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "\[\033[32m\]cheese\[\033[0m\]"
$ export PS1="\$(./green_cheese.sh) \$"
\[\]cheese\[\] $ # <- FAIL!
```

Is there a particular escape sequence I can use from the external command to achieve the desired result? Or is there a way I can manually tell the prompt how many characters to set the prompt width to?

Assume that I can print anything I like from the external command, and that this command can be quite intelligent (for example, counting characters in the output). I can also make the `export PS1=...` command as complicated as required. **However, the escape codes for the colors must come from the external command.**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I couldn't tell you exactly *why* this works, but replace `\[` and `\]` with the actual characters that `bash` generates from them in your prompt:

```
echo -e "\001\033[32m\002cheese\001\033[0m\002"
```

[I learned this from some Stack Overflow post that I cannot find now.]

If I had to guess, it's that `bash` replaces `\[` and `\]` with the two ASCII characters before executing the command that's embedded in the prompt, so that by the time `green_cheese.sh` completes, it's too late for `bash` to process the wrappers correctly, and so they are treated literally. One way to avoid this is to use `PROMPT_COMMAND` to build your prompt dynamically, rather than embedding executable code in the value of `PS1`.

```
prompt_cmd () {
    PS1="$(green_cheese.sh)"
    PS1+=' \$ '
}

PROMPT_COMMAND=prompt_cmd
```

This way, the `\[` and `\]` are added to `PS1` when it is *defined*, not when it is *evaluated*, so you don't need to use `\001` and `\002` directly.

Comment: Thank you. This works perfectly! Actually, now I know the escape codes to use, I found the other posts that you refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22706988/341459 http://stackoverflow.com/a/14637194/341459 http://stackoverflow.com/a/19501528/341459

Comment: You're entirely right. `\001` and `\002`, aka RL_PROMPT_START_IGNORE and RL_PROMPT_END_IGNORE, are a poorly documented [readline feature](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/readline.git/tree/display.c?id=fb914b20839322c962918590b3ea449555d7d9f9#n262). Bash converts `\[..\]` to `\001..\002` for Readline, but neglects to escape existing ones so that this implementation detail leaks through (and it's so useful that you can hardly call it a bug).

Comment: When I saw `PROMPT_COMMAND` on a recent post I remembered this question and went back to it but it seems like the idea was already given. I also had the idea that bash may actually be producing characters out of `\[` and `\]` and tried to examine it but the output of `ttyrec` was just confusing so I just gave up. +1 btw.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't edit the code generating the string containing ANSI color / control codes, you can wrap them after the fact.

The following will enclose ANSI control sequences in ASCII `SOH` (`^A`) and `STX` (`^B`) [which are equivalent to `\[` and `\]` respectively](https://superuser.com/a/301355/365890):

```
function readline_ANSI_escape() {
  if [[ $# -ge 1 ]]; then
    echo "$*"
  else
    cat  # Read string from STDIN
  fi | \
  perl -pe 's/(?:(?<!\x1)|(?<!\\\[))(\x1b\[[0-9;]*[mG])(?!\x2|\\\])/\x1\1\x2/g'
}
```

Use it like:

```
$ echo $'\e[0;1;31mRED' | readline_ANSI_escape
```

Or:

```
$ readline_ANSI_escape "$string"
```

As a bonus, running the function multiple times will not re-escape already escaped control codes.

Answer (score -1):

I suspect that if you echo the value of `$PS1` after your first example, you’ll find that its value is the word “cheese” in green. (At least, that’s what I see when I run your example.) At first glance, this is what you want — the word “cheese” in green! Except that what you *really* wanted was the word cheese *preceded by the escape codes* that *produce* green. What you did by using the `-e` flag for echo is produce a value with the escape codes *already evaluated*.

That *happens* to work for the specification of colors, but as you’ve found, it mangles the “non-printing sequence” markers into something the `$PS1` interpreter doesn’t properly understand.

Fortunately, the solution is simple: drop the `-e` flag. `echo` will then leave the escape sequences untouched, and the `$PS1` interpreter will Do The Right Thing™.

Comment: sounds fair, does not work. chepner described already how the escaping happens *before* the external command is called.